# Case distinct statement in Tableau

Tags: sql, tableau-api

I have a query that I would like to run using my data visualization tool (Tableau), however when I tried to retrieve records using SQL query based on distinct(id) as shown below data, I am receiving error on "Expected: CASE, CAST, DEFAULT, EXISTS, FALSE, IF, INTERVAL, NOT, NULL, REPLACE, TRUNCATE, TRUE, IDENTIFIER CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error"

The data looks somethings like this

```
tablename | id | records
table_1     3    344
table_2     4    222
table_1     3    344
table_2     4    222
```

Expected output

```
tablename | id | record 
table_1    3     344
table_2    4     222
```

This is the query that I used

```
case when id = distinct(id) then 'distinct value' else 'not required' end
```

I have also tried
`distinct(id)` but seems visualization BI is expecting me to use case instead. By any chance I am doing this query wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL statement is invalid. You can try this-

```
SELECT table_name, id, MAX(record) FROM table GROUP BY table_name, id
```